# Execution context for code after await inside Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

Maybe I misunderstood something, but I always think that by default, when an incomplete Task is awaited, the current “context” is captured and used to resume the method when the Task completes. But I found quite strange behavior (at least for me) where this is wrong:

```
private static Task StartTask()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("StartTask thread id = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });
}

private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread id before await task = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            await StartTask().ConfigureAwait(true);
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread id after await task = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });
}
```

and I receive such result in debug output

```
Thread id before await task = 12
StartTask thread id = 13
Thread id after await task = 13
```

Why did code execution context change after await?

Comment: Sorry, found answer to my question: for continuation will be used Default (ThreadPool) SynchronizationContext http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

Comment: Then you should post that as an answer and then accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> by default, when an incomplete Task is awaited, the current “context” is captured and used to resume the method when the Task completes

That's correct. The behavior you observed is correct.

The question is: what is the "context" that is captured? It is the current `SynchronizationContext`, unless it is `null`, in which case it is the current `TaskScheduler`.

When `Task.Run` executes your delegate, it is executing it on the thread pool. Thus, there is no current `SynchronizationContext`. So the current `TaskScheduler` is used; note that since there is not actually a task executing (the delegate is executed directly on the thread pool), the current `TaskScheduler` is the default `TaskScheduler`, which represents the thread pool.